# psql - Mac trying to connect postgreSQL in Ubuntu system installed in a virtual machine in remote server

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, remote-access, psql

Apologize in front, maybe the situation here is a bit complicated. I searched everywhere online but couldn't find a perfect solution, plus I have tried almost all the solutions mentioned in other posts.

- **Situation:**

So I have a postgreSQL database installed in a Ubuntu system. The system is actually a virtual machine on the VMware workstation 12, which is installed on Windows 7 professional. Now I am trying to remotely access the postgreSQL database through my MacBook pro 2013.

In the Mac terminal, the command line I tried is:

> psql -U postgres -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xx

"xxx.xxx.xxx.xx" represents the IP address of the Windows 7 machine. The result is a failure:

> psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
>       Is the server running on host "169.254.121.2" and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

- **What I have done:**

  1. Edited the pg_hba.conf file to include

> host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

2. Edited the postgresql.conf to include

> listen_addresses='*'

3. Restarted postgres service.
4. Disabled firewall on the host.
5. I checked by running the psql command locally and it worked. **Also, on the same VMware I have other Ubuntu systems. They are all fine to connect and access the data in this Ubuntu system.**
6. Running Nmap, the output is

> PORT STATE SERVICE
>
> 5432/TCP open postgresql

- **What's next?** Anything else I can try? Any advice is highly appreciated and please let me know if anything above is ambiguous. I will clarify for better diagnosis. Thank you all!

Comment: _Operation timed out_ means the TCP packets are getting dropped. Generally, a firewall does that. You don't need to do anything more on the postgres configuration.

Comment: @DanielVérité Hi Daniel, thanks for your comment! I think you are very right. Please refer to the below answer as I somehow solved the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow managed to get it working..

So when I ran "Nmap" on the other Ubuntu system towards this one, it does shows

> PORT STATE SERVICE
>
> 5432/TCP open postgresql

However, when I ran "Nmap" on my Mac, it's a different port, 3389, which is mainly used for Windows remote desktop. So what I did was to check the network configuration of this Ubuntu virtual machine from "**bridged**" to "**NAT**" and did a **port forwarding** to 5432. It is working fine now..

I read in some places saying that VMware favors bridged whereas VirtualBox favors NAT+port forwarding. I am quite confused as it is certain not the case in my situation. Maybe I am wrong.